# How to fix SSL problem with WordPress pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, digicert

I am working with my new website. I got SSL certificates file from Digicert SSL provider . I installed SSL as instructed . But my WordPress pages  still get Insecure page error while other html and non-WordPress PHP pages works Okay. I am not sure what did i do wrong.
my website is

https://www.devbhusal.com/    shows insecure page error.

https://www.devbhusal.com/readme.html  works fine.

https://www.devbhusal.com/test.php  works fine.

Comment: There is awesome site called [Why no Paddlock](https://www.whynopadlock.com/results/dd7387e6-53b0-410c-b3b8-09c55df479a6) - the link leads directly to results of your main domain. TL;DR: Seems like you did not install the certificate properly, because its self signed. Consider using [Lets Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) certificate

Answer (score 1):

If SSL installed successfully with domain and still site is not secure then please check if internal link used only http:// if yes then convert to https:// and still you not able to find then you can use https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/ plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with simpl SSL and everything that I can find on internet. At last I made wordpress backup file, created new server in EC2 ,install fresh WordPress ,restore wordpress data and install SSL. Now it is working. I still couldn't figure out what went wrong with old settings.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on this point. I am trying to migrate a wordpress project to ec2. Now SSL are causing issues.
Uncaught Error: Class "WpOrg\\Requests\\Utility\\InputValidator" not found in /var/www/html/wp-includes/Requests/src/Requests.php:635